# How to write on right way factorys AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found this styleguide for angularjs:

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#factories

I wana now to write my code on that way:

Here is my working factory:

```
.factory('Noty',function($http){
           return{
               update:function(NotificationData){
                   return $http ({
                        method: "PUT",
                        url   : "/api/notification/" + NotificationData.task,
                        data  : NotificationData
                   });
               }
           };
        });
```

How can I rewrite it to look like in document above?

```
/* recommended */
function dataService() {
    var someValue = '';
    var service = {
        save: save,
        someValue: someValue,
        validate: validate
    };
    return service;

    ////////////

    function save() {
        /* */
    };

    function validate() {
        /* */
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd write it like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var factoryNotyModule = angular.module('yourApp.factory.Noty', []);


    factoryNotyModule.factory('Noty', Noty);

    Noty.$inject = ['$http'];
    function Noty($http) {

        function updateData (NotificationData) {
            return $http({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: '/api/notification/' + NotificationData.task,
                data: NotificationData
            });
        }

        return {
            updateData: updateData
        };
    }
})();
```

So that you can use it after you inject it somewhere:

```
Noty.updateData(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple, as you are already using a factory with the [revealing module pattern](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/):

```
.factory('Noty', function ($http) {
    var service = {
        update : update
    };

    return service;

    function update(NotificationData) {
        return $http({
            method : "PUT",
            url : "/api/notification/" + NotificationData.task,
            data : NotificationData
        });
    }
});
```